# Detect if the html element is being pushed to the new line on zoom or windows larger text size

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, bootstrap-5

I have 2 labels side by side and because of the system text size 150%(which is recommended) in the windows, the second label is not having enough space and it floats below. I just want to just find out if the second label is going into the new line or not using javascript or css. So that I can change the 1st label accordingly.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<label class="form-label fw-bold">testing out label1</label>
<label (click)="method()" class="float-end fw-bolder">
        <em class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></em>
        testing label 2 testing
      </label>
```

when the label2 is being pushed below, I want to remove the text "testing out" from label1.
Note: the browser will be on 100% zoom only when the windows is having text size of 150%.

Comment: This sounds like you are planning some scripted correction to a layout problem that you might be able to solve by means of CSS? This is, most of the time, quite fragile. Could you share more about your issue?

Comment: Otherwise, what have you tried? Did you try to compare `el1.offsetTop < el2.offsetTop`?

Comment: I have so far tried to get the distance from the top of the screen for both the label by this... document.getElementById('label1')?.getBoundingClientRect()?.top but even after the label 2 is getting pushed below, the top for both the elements is coming same.

Comment: @Andy I have update the question.

Comment: Unfortunately your code example is not reproducing the issue as in [Reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The class `float-end` only exists as of Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your situation and using `getBoundingClientRect()` does work. For me it returns 24 as a difference.

Even if I zoom (text-only) until the second element completely wraps into the second line, it’s providing a difference.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  [l1, l2] = document.querySelectorAll('.label');
  alert(l2.getBoundingClientRect().top- l1.getBoundingClientRect().top);
});

document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').addEventListener('change', e => document.querySelector('.wrapper').classList.toggle('narrow', e.currentTarget.checked));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

.narrow {
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="form-label fw-bold label">testing out label1</span>
  <span class="float-right fw-bolder label">
    <em class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></em> testing label 2 testing
  </span>
</div>

<label><input type="checkbox"> Make elements wrap</label>
<br>
<button>Get difference in top coordinates</button>
```